# How to retrieve json data from custom json enpoint created from a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I was able to make a json endpoint with WordPress's rewrite rule API.

Here's how:

```
// Add custom rewrite rule

function test_rewrite_rule() {

    add_rewrite_tag( '%movies%', '([^&]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'movie-api/([^&]+)/?', 'index.php?movies=$matches[1]', 'top' );

}
add_action( 'init', 'test_rewrite_rule' );

// outputting the data

function test_movie_endpoint_data() {

    global $wp_query;

    $movie_tag = $wp_query->get( 'movies' );

    if ( ! $movie_tag ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( $movie_tag == 'all' ) {
        $movie_tag = false;
    }

    $movie_data = array();

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'movies',
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
        'moxie_tag'    => esc_attr( $movie_tag ),
    );

    $movie_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $movie_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $movie_query->have_posts() ) :       
    $movie_query->the_post();

    $movie_data[] = array(
        'id'    => get_the_id(),
        'title' => get_the_title(),
        'poster_url' => esc_url( test_get_meta('poster_url') ),
        'rating' => test_get_meta('rating'), 
        'year' => test_get_meta('year'),
        'short_description' => test_get_meta('description'),
    );
    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
    endif;

    wp_send_json( $movie_data );

} 
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'test_movie_endpoint_data' );
```

But while I try toretrieve the json data with wordpress's wp_remote_get(), curl or file_get_contents() it's returning NULL.

Any idea what's the best way to get those information on the front end form the end point?

Comment: Instead of creating end points via rewrite api i suggest you to take a look at WP REST API it's being developed and being integrated into WP core.
For custom post type end points, you can take a look at this
http://torquemag.io/adding-custom-routes-wordpress-rest-api/

Comment: Thank for you the suggestion @bravokeyl . But it requires the Wp API plugin If I ain't mistaken. I'd like to have the endpoint integrated into my plugin. Do you have any alternative thoughts on it? Thanks again for your time

Comment: WP Rest API is being merged into core, wait for the boom, for now i don't have any suggestion